# как автозаполнить input при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, html, input

Необходимо заполнить тег input при загрузке страницы текстом "Самовывоз". Внимание! placeholder , value - не подходят, нужно именно ДЕЙСТВИЕ. Ниже прикрепил код, думаю, что реализацию можно осуществить на js, но я в нем не силен...прошу помощи!

```
<form class="dostavka" method="POST" action="">
  <input id="test-inp">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const inp = document.querySelector('#test-inp');
  if (inp) inp.value = 'Самовывоз';
});
```

```html
<form class="dostavka" method="POST" action="javascript:void(0)">
  <input id="test-inp">
</form>
```

---

С задержкой в 1 секунду:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const inp = document.querySelector('#test-inp');
  if (inp) setTimeout(() => inp.value = 'Самовывоз', 1e3);
});
```

```html
<form class="dostavka" method="POST" action="javascript:void(0)">
  <input id="test-inp">
</form>
```

---

##### MDN:

- [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)
- [Атрибут `value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-value) элемента `<input>` (одноименное DOM-свойство работает с этим атрибутом)

Comment: спасибо, можно ли сделать это автозаполнение через определенное время? например, через секунду после загрузки страницы?

Comment: @Матвей, да, можно.

Comment: @Матвей, сорри, я собирался добавить пример с задержкой, но отвлекли и забыл про эту вкладку - теперь добавил.